# Codable Error: Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, dictionary, swiftui

Have checked prior similar posts but can't find a resolution in my specific case. Specifically this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63496219/swift-jsondecoder-error-expected-to-decode-dictionarystring-any-but-found-a) but the approved response didnt resolve my issue.

I have a SwiftUI app connected to Firebase. I've created a map containing a user's most recent entry consisting of date (of type date), and height, weight, and BMI (all as type double), as well a second a map containing arrays of all [dates], [heights], [weights], and [BMIs].

This is my code. I suspect it has to do with the way I'm decoding it? Data is saving properly into my firebase console but when I go to load the data the getuser function fails and I get this decoding error:

> Error fetching user data: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "all_health_data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct LatestHealthDataEntry: Codable {
    var date: Date
    var height: Double
    var weight: Double
    var bmi: Double
}

struct AllHealthDataEntries: Codable {
    var date: [Date]
    var height: [Double]
    var weight: [Double]
    var bmi: [Double]
}

struct DBUser: Codable {
    let userId: String
    let isAnonymous: Bool?
    let email: String?
    let photoUrl: String?
    let dateCreated: Date?
    let isPremium: Bool?
    let name: String?
    var latestHealthData: LatestHealthDataEntry?
    var allHealthData: AllHealthDataEntries?
    
    init(auth: AuthDataResultModel) {
        self.userId = auth.uid
        self.isAnonymous = auth.isAnonymous
        self.email = auth.email
        self.photoUrl = auth.photoUrl
        self.dateCreated = Date()
        self.isPremium = false
        self.name = auth.name
        self.latestHealthData = nil
        self.allHealthData = nil
    }
    
    init(
     userId: String,
     isAnonymous: Bool? = nil,
     email: String? = nil,
     photoUrl: String? = nil,
     dateCreated: Date? = nil,
     isPremium: Bool? = nil,
     name: String? = nil,
     latestHealthData: LatestHealthDataEntry? = nil,
     allHealthData: AllHealthDataEntries? = nil
    ) {
        self.userId = userId
        self.isAnonymous = isAnonymous
        self.email = email
        self.photoUrl = photoUrl
        self.dateCreated = dateCreated
        self.isPremium = isPremium
        self.name = name
        self.latestHealthData = latestHealthData
        self.allHealthData = allHealthData
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userId = "user_id"
        case isAnonymous = "is_anonymous"
        case email = "email"
        case photoUrl = "photo_url"
        case dateCreated = "date_created"
        case isPremium = "is_Premium"
        case name = "name"
        case latestHealthData = "latest_health_data"
        case allHealthData = "all_health_data"
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.userId, forKey: .userId)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(self.isAnonymous, forKey: .isAnonymous)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(self.email, forKey: .email)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(self.photoUrl, forKey: .photoUrl)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(self.dateCreated, forKey: .dateCreated)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(self.isPremium, forKey: .isPremium)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(self.name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(self.latestHealthData, forKey: .latestHealthData)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(self.allHealthData, forKey: .allHealthData)
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.userId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .userId)
        self.isAnonymous = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isAnonymous)
        self.email = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
        self.photoUrl = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .photoUrl)
        self.dateCreated = try container.decodeIfPresent(Date.self, forKey: .dateCreated)
        self.isPremium = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isPremium)
        self.name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.latestHealthData = try container.decodeIfPresent(LatestHealthDataEntry.self, forKey: .latestHealthData)
        self.allHealthData = try container.decodeIfPresent(AllHealthDataEntries.self, forKey: .allHealthData)
    }
}

final class UserManager {
    
    static let shared = UserManager()
    private init() {}
    
    private let userCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
    
    private let encoder: Firestore.Encoder = {
        let encoder = Firestore.Encoder()
        return encoder
    }()
    
    private let decoder: Firestore.Decoder = {
        let decoder = Firestore.Decoder()
        return decoder
    }()
    
    private func userDocument(userId: String) -> DocumentReference {
        userCollection.document(userId)
    }
    
    func createNewUser(user: DBUser) async throws {
        try userDocument(userId: user.userId).setData(from: user, merge: true)
    }
    
    func getUser(userId: String) async throws -> DBUser {
        return try await userDocument(userId: userId).getDocument(as: DBUser.self)
    }
    
    func updateUserPremiumStatus(userId: String, isPremium: Bool) async throws {
        let data: [String:Any] = [
            DBUser.CodingKeys.isPremium.rawValue : isPremium
        ]
        try await userDocument(userId: userId).updateData(data)
    }
    
    func addHealthDataEntry(userId: String, healthDataEntry: AllHealthDataEntries) async throws {
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(healthDataEntry) else {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }
        let dict: [String:Any] = [
            DBUser.CodingKeys.allHealthData.rawValue : FieldValue.arrayUnion([data])
        ]
        try await userDocument(userId: userId).updateData(dict)
    }
    
    func updateNewestHealthDataEntry(userId: String, healthDataEntry: LatestHealthDataEntry) async throws {
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(healthDataEntry) else {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }
        let dict: [String:Any] = [
            DBUser.CodingKeys.latestHealthData.rawValue : data
        ]
        
        try await userDocument(userId: userId).updateData(dict)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: the value of `allHealthData` is an array (`[AllHealthDataEntries]`)